# Font-Awesome Icon not appearing

Tags: css, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap4 and Font-Awesome together.
I know Bootstrap4 is working fine because all classes I'm using from Bootstrap4 work fine. However, this is my first time working with Font-Awesome and I really don't know why the icons aren't appearing.
I fetched FontAwesome using this in my head.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then later I use.

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <br /><br /><br />
    <i class="icon-search"></i> <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for a City" />
</div>
```

I used this documentation: http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/search/
Also, my network tab says that font-awesome has been fetched with a status of 200.

Comment: You are including fontawesome `4.7.0` and using the document from the `3.2.1`.

Comment: Your syntax should look like: `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the CDN for `3.2.1`version, everything is working fine.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
    <br /><br /><br />
    <i class="icon-search"></i> <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for a City" />
</div>
```

If you want to use `4.7.0`, you have to do it like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container text-center">
        <br /><br /><br />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for a City" />
    </div>
```

Documentation from `v4`: http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/